# tinyfiledialogs how to save file in russian naming folder

Tags: c#, .net, save, dllimport, intptr

I am using tinyfiledialogs lib and i am able to save files in folders which names are in English but when i try to  save the exact same file in folder which name is like for example "Кот"  in other words in Russian letter i could not.

This is the code

```
IntPtr p = tinyfd_saveFileDialog(sDialogTitle, sInitialPathAndFile, 
            filterPatterns.Length, filterPatterns, sPatternDesc);
```

This is defined in somelib that i am using

```
        [DllImport("tinyfiledialogs", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr tinyfd_saveFileDialog(string aTitle, string aDefaultPathAndFile, int aNumOfFilterPatterns, string[] aFilterPatterns, string aSingleFilterDescription);
```

Any help?I am newbee to this lib and could not find any essential information regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: I've just corrected many things in the C# import of the DLLs. Can you give a try to version 3.6.0 with the new DLLs ?

I am the author of tinyfiledialogs. First make sure you are getting it from the sourceforge site https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyfiledialogs and not from any of the github copies (generally out of date).

As reported you should use the UTF-16 (wchar_t - CharSet = CharSet.Unicode) calls. But UTF-8 (char = CharSet.Ansi) also works now.

Comment: how can i know which source i am using? And how can i get the source from sourcfroge site?Any links?

Comment: Yep you were right, i have downloaded the latest version of your library and it seems like it is working correctly.I have been using old version so far. Which had some issues with non English named folders.Anyway thank you.

Comment: Hi again, could you please tell me is there pecific version of your library for macOs or this dll's should wokork fine on both windows and macOs?

Comment: I have just added the .dylib file to the zip file on sourceforge. But you could produce it yourself, like this: "clang -c tinyfiledialogs.c" and then "clang -dynamiclib tinyfiledialogs.o -o tinyfiledialogs.dylib".

Answer (score 2):

The library appears to export both ANSI and Unicode versions (i.e. A and W suffixes) of its functions. So you should just be able to change

```
CharSet = CharSet.Ansi
```

to

```
CharSet = CharSet.Unicode
```

and the pinvoke marshaler will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks but when i changed the ansi to unicode pop up was not shown at al.

Comment: Probably some other issue. But you are going to need to use Unicode, aren't you?

Comment: Yep, or i might use auto option duno right now but in act with unicode pop up was not shown at all. Trying to figure out what is wrong,

Comment: You don't want to use `Auto`. I mean, you aren't targeting Windows 98.

Comment: Ohh right)I just do not know why with Unicode this thing is not working

Comment: We can't see how you are calling the function.